# Is it possible to create something like PageObjects with SeeTest?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, mobile, seetest

We reflect on using SeeTest for mobile app test automation. I am familiar with Selenium 2 / WebDriver and like to use PageObjects.

Is it possible to create PageObjects or something similar with SeeTest? The SeeTest test automation can be developed with Java or other programming languages, so it should be possible. But I have no experience with this tool and I want to play safe.

Thanks for your support!

> PageObject: A class for a page or component of a page which provides all
> elements and actions. This way it is possible to write easy to understand test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SeeTest there is out-of-box concept called **Zone**.

> Zones are similar to containers and allow to group elements as you wish. It's obvious to group elements by functional areas / pages / screens. So Zones are similar to Page Objects in some sense.

Here are few Zone-related official help pages:

- [Terminology > Zone](http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/Zone-Term.htm)
- [Add a new Zone](http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/New_Zone.htm)

---

To develop your own implementation of PageObject, or extend Zones with some behaviour

- **you can also export test code into regular programming language**.
  Find info here: [Help](http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/help.htm) > Plug-in & Add-on to 3rd party framework

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Sounds good. But is it right, that zones only provide elements? Element actions like click, type and something similar can not implemented by myself? For exmaple `zone.clickNextButton();` or `zone.searchFor(String);` In this example `searchFor(String);` select a search field, type the String and select the submit button. So the method interact with multiple elements. Is something like that possible?

Comment: I think yes. I've updated an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to maintain SeeTest automation using POM because if we declare all the paths like

```
public static By launchpad_button = By.xpath("//*[@id='text']");
```

but the commands in SeeTest are like below

```
driver.client.elementSendText("NATIVE", "xpath=//*[@id='text']", 0 ,"Testing");
```

So you need to add xpath again while using SeeTest commands

> Its useful in the Selenium + Webdriver but i thinks it will wast in
>   Selenium Webdriver + SeeTest